# ObjectListView: select subitem programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, objectlistview

How can I select a subitem of an [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) programmatically?

`SelectObject()` and `SelectItem()` work only with root items, not with subitems.

Comment: You're ObjectListView Link doesn't work.

Comment: Daryl, sanks for your comment - i fix it.

Comment: does it have somethinglike `ObjectListView.Items[index].Select`?? normally there should be some sort of access to items depending on theire index or subitems they have. look in its methods.

Comment: Sean87, no there is no methods, like you wrote. Threr is problem, that the root item of that tree its OLVListItem, with has Select property, that can select my root item. But all subitems of each OLVListItem - its OLVList**Sub**Item, and OLVListSubItem doesnot have a selected property, or select method.

Comment: Are you sure there can be child items on the `ObjectListView` object you use? It seems to me for example (from what I see on their screenshots), that the `ListView` doesn't have child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem. It can be useful for anybody, who have similar problem. For this, I need to change a source code of control by next:

Change access type for `TreeModel` property in `TreeListView` class from `protected` to `public`. After this I have access to manipulate `Branch` objects of `TreeListView` object. For example, to select any subitem of root element I write next code:

```
var branch = tlvMain.TreeModel.GetBranch(tlvMain.SelectedObject);
var children = branch.Children.Cast<SecurityObject>().ToList();
tlvMain.SelectObject(children.SingleOrDefault(p=>p.Id == soft.Id));
```

Answer (score 2):

The things called subitems in an ObjectListView are actually the strings and images that show in the columns.

If you actually want to use the ObjectListView then the most direct way to select a subitem is

```
objectListView1.Items[index].SubItems[index]
```

If you use a TreeListView then you should use the method you already found.
Though I recommend selecting and changing in the source instead.