# Get TreeListView cell value programmatically in ObjectListView

Tags: objectlistview

How can I programmatically obtain the value of a cell in OLV's treeListView using the row and column index?

```
treeListView.GetItem(0).GetSubItemAt(6,e.rowIndex).Text
```

for example does not appear to work, it just gives me the string value of the first cell of the first row. Also I do not understand the answer here:

[ObjectListView: select subitem programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083810/objectlistview-select-subitem-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the sub items is not recommended and you should never have to access them when using the ObjectListView/TreeListView controls.

You should retrieve the model object of the required row instead, and then access the property that is related to the column/cell in question.

You can retrieve the model with

```
MyModel model = objectListView1.GetModelObject(rowIndex) as MyModel
```

where MyModel is your underlying model class.